# Xcode: Failed to launch macOS command-line program due to permission issue

Tags: xcode, macos, permissions, code-signing

### Environment

- macOS Catalina 10.15.7
- Xcode 12.3

### Problem

My macOS command-line application, written in C++, runs ok inside Xcode or as a standalone program in Terminal. But fails to launch when run as a child process from other programs.

The error message looks like this

[image]

### Efforts

I've looked through my project's provisioning settings.
My team profile is only one-day past its life span. And the project still builds so I doubt that is the issue. I then switched to another certificate that is still healthy but saw the same problem with the child process failure.

I've also checked security settings and there are no permission blocks or anything like that. I've built this program many times and sorted out all the permission issues before. There used to be no problem running it as a child process.

### Question

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution myself.

I had to remove the code signature using

```sh
codesign --remove-signature
```

Then sign it normally through Xcode.

It is most probably caused by our team switching signing identity and  deprecating the old one.

Another related fix:

This error also happens when I run any script that launches child processes of executables built myself inside an IDE.

The solution is to add the IDE to

```sh
System Preferences > Security & Privacy > Privacy > Developer Tools
```